# How to count the unique visitors via Laravel and display them in a chart?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-4

I want to make a overview of my unique visitors (a bit like cloudflare does) via Laravel.

What I already have:

I have a database sheme, but I don't think that is is good:
[image: db sheme]

I want to store as much as possible data into my database, but not the place, which browser etc...

I want to be able to view all visitors (unique, so not twice the same IP in one day) per day, so count the IP adressess, and that the whole month long.

For example:

The month April needs to be displayed in my view like this:

```
['1/04', 5],
['2/04', 58],
['3/04', 496],
['4/04', 654],
['5/04', 854],
['6/04', 756],
['7/04', 254],
['8/04', 887],
['9/04', 452],
['10/04', 985],
['11/04', 745],
['12/04', 120],
['13/04', 985],
['14/04', 745],
['15/04', 321],
['16/04', 852],
['17/04', 753],
['18/04', 951],
['19/04', 791],
['20/04', 167],
['21/04', 761],
['22/04', 349],
['23/04', 741],
['24/04', 258],
['25/04', 963],
['26/04', 317],
['27/04', 482],
['28/04', 341],
['29/04', 654],
['30/04', 751]
```

So every day the number of IP's must been counted and that for a month long, wich will depends on the currend month.

The output will look simmular to this:

[image: Output]

I would like to receive an controller, view and database sheme, if possible.
I searched already the whole internet, but didn't found anything...
If someone could help me, I would be very pleased!

Kindest regards,

Robin

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I understand your goal correctly, this is the way I would solve the issue.

Make these changes to your database:

```
1) Remove the hits field.

2) Store dates in a YYYY-MM-DD format.
```

Then check for an existing record in the database or create a new one when the new user logins or requests a page (you should probably cache this reduce hits on the DB):

```
$visitor = Visit::firstOrCreate(['date'=>$current_date,'ip'=>$ip_address);
```

Then when it is time to retrieve the data for your view you can call:

```
$visits = Visit::selectRaw('date count(date) as hits'))->groupBy('date')->whereRaw("`date` between $begin and $end")->get();
```

This should get you going, but you'll have to work out the views and such on your own.

Comment: This helped me alot! But the major problem now is, I can't select them from the database. My query looks like this: http://prntscr.com/72xz8f and raw does it look like this: http://prntscr.com/72xzew But as output I get nothing. Not one result. I executed the query in navicat and this is what I have: http://prntscr.com/72xzrc Yes I do have records in my database between that two dates.

Comment: After I did some research, I found a solution. The output I've got is this: http://laravel.io/bin/BLyM3 The problem now is that my javascript code doesn't take the values like that. The `{}` must been replaced by `[]` and the first `[]` need to disappear.

Comment: Are you calling `$visits->toJson()` before you return it to JavaScript?

Answer (score 2):

The main problem of this architecture is that MySql is not good at aggregations. What you need is aggregated data inside time series. For this you can use `Cassandra` time series or a `MongoDb` approach.

When a new unique ip is inserted in db following nested inserts are performed:

1. Number of hits for current year is increased
2. Number of hits for current month is increased
3. Number of hits for current week is increased
4. Number of hits for current day is increased
5. Number of hits for current hour is increased
6. Number of hits for current minute is increased.

For instance when a new hit is recorded at 2015-06-14 23:11:23 in a MongoDb strategy:

```
{
_id : MongoId(),
year : 2015,
hits : ++,
months : {
    6 : {
        hits : ++,
        days : {
            14 : {
                hits : ++,
                hours : {
                    23 : {
                        hits : ++,
                        minutes : {
                            11 : {
                                hits : ++
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

With this strategy you can query a date range limited by minute with a nice time complexity.

You can also use `Redis` if you only need the recent data (for example only the last month). Which then you `increment` site hits for `current_month`, `day_14_of_current_month`, `hour_23_of_current_day`, `minute_23_of_current_hour` as your aggregation keys. Redis retrieves a single key with `O(1)` complexity, and multiple keys (for example day 0 to 5th of current month) with `O(n)`.

I have used the `Redis` approach to provide statistics for a [bit.ly](http://bitly.com) like website written in Laravel 5, after each request a rabbitmq message was being published with request ip data, multiple workers concurrently pop jobs, and insert the aggregation data into redis, so the statistics were near real time.

Comment: I'm not formilliar to mongodb, cassandra or redis, could you maybe explain me how I can integrate everything or how my database must look like? I need this solution soon, because without this option I can't put my app online. Already thanks for the amazing effort!